# Where to download Oracle 11g (11.2.0.4.0) client for windows server 2012

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have been searching download oracle client 11g(11.2.0.4.0) for windows server 2012.

I have looking at oracle website still cannot get it.

Where can I download?

Comment: [Try looking here. Best of luck.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html)

Comment: Thanks. I have checked that one. it is not the one I want. Actually I want to use sql loader (sqlldr) command on windows server 2012. I have installed oracle client 11g (11.2.0.3) on windows server 2012, but sql loader is not there.

Comment: I would expect `sqlldr` to be part of the database product, not the client.

Comment: It is included in client installation which I am using my laptop windows 7 64bit. Same installation on windows server 2012 but during installation got message [INS-13001] Environment does not meet minimum requirements. I have checked this one on the net, one place suggest to install Oracle client 11g (11.2.0.4 ) 64 bit. I still cannot find it.

Comment: What sort of client installation did you do?  There are lots of different ways to install the Oracle client which install (or don't install) various utilities.  If you have a full client install, my wager is that you did an installation that just didn't include SQL*Loader.  If you do a custom install, you can pick and choose what is installed and choose whichever tools you want.

Comment: I think Instant Client doesn't include SQL Loader.  You need the full client for that.  However, Oracle only offer [the base 11gR2 release of the client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win32soft-098987.html) for download.  Getting to 11.2.0.4 means patching, which requires a Support contract.

Comment: Thanks all. I have installed 12C client and working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Go to this link https://updates.oracle.com/Orion/PatchDetails/process_form?patch_num=13390677

and download Oracle client(11.2.0.4) 64 bit which is  p13390677_112040_platform_4of7.zip

For 32 bit you need to download p13390677_112040_platform_3of6.zip